# Converse of Statement with Limits

Tags: calculus, logic

I am trying to find the find the converse of "If $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ then the sequence $s_n = \frac{x_n}{x_n +1}$ converges." Would the converse just be "If the sequence $s_n = \frac{x_n}{x_n +1}$ converges then $x_n \rightarrow \infty$?"

Also, I want to prove the converse false by saying that if $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ the hypothesis of the converse is satisfied, but the conclusion is false, so the statement is false. Have I made any errors in my reasoning?

Comment: No, your reasoning is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to your first question. Your disproof of the converse is correct. Here is another way. If $x_n = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\frac{x_n}{x_n+1} = \frac12$ and certainly converges as $n \to \infty$, but clearly $x_n \not\to \infty$.